# how to drag n drop group position of expandablelistview in android

Tags: android, listview, expandablelistview

Can u please help me out of this things...
how to drag n drop group from one to next position vertically??

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this powerful library:

https://github.com/h6ah4i/android-advancedrecyclerview

This is exactly what you need. Hope it helps!

Comment: Thankz for answering

Comment: Yeah i saw this example already but i have an issue for drag n drop parent position from one to another position in ExpandableListView not their childs...

Comment: yeah bro very good library thnks for doing this but i can not find my solutions for posted this question..

Comment: Realy... you wrong my friend, please do the following: open Google Play Store application on your device, search for "Advanced RecyclerView Examples", download the app, open it. There are four tabs - "DRAG", "SWIPE", "EXPAND", "ADVANCED". Click on "ADVANCED" and click the middle button "EXPANDABLE + DRAGGABLE + SWIPABLE". This is exactly what you want - draggable group items.

Comment: Let me know how to achieve the drag and drop with an expandable list view. @IvanIvanov